# Cuando voy a importar mas de dos iconos de "React Icons" la página me se queda en blanco

Tags: reactjs

Cuando importo mas de dos componentes que son iconos la página se queda en blanco. Inicié el proyecto de ReacJs con Vite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArLex.png).

Si dejo solo dos o uno, me funciona perfectamente.

¿Alguien sabe por qué es?

He intendado buscar solucion pero aun no encuentra nada util

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, procura colocar el codigo como texto y no como enlaces externos ni como imagees. Te invito a que te des una vuelta por el [tour], de igual manera leas [ask] y como proveer un [repro]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fijate que las dos primeras letras de los dos primeros imports (Ri) coinciden con el path de al importacion "react-icons/ri"

deberias importar el HiOutlineMenuAlt1 desde su carpeta correspondiente:

```
 import { HiOutlineMenuAlt1 } from 'react-icons/hi"
```